# {% load static %} Shown as a text line in html opened on browser

Tags: html, django, templatetags

Im trying to use templatetags, but when i write {% load static %} on top of html document and run, it takes this as a text, and does not load the static.

I set the static config in settings.py but stills not working

```
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

when i open the file on browser or when i send the template via email, as expected in the proyect, the css works, but the images doesnt. I realized i'd use the static dir, but the line: {% load static %} is shown in the browser as text.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the page?

Comment: It sounds like you are serving this template directly, rather than referring it. Show your view.

Comment: mm if you can help me, im new in SO, how do i post the screenshot here?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps below,

- In "settings.py" set STATIC_URL = '/static/'
- In your template ensure you type {% load static %}, do note that there should be a space between the percentage symbol "%" and the word "static". From your code snippet above this seems to be the source of the problem.
- Ensure all your static files are stored in a folder named static as such "/static//example.jpg."  then in the html file image tag should be "/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">.

Do note that the method stated above is only suitable during the development stage. You can read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) for more information